# jQuery UI addClass(class, duration) not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, addclass, removeclass

I am sure I have had this working before, but under jQuery UI 1.7.2 and 1.8.7 it appears that `addClass(class, duration)` is no longer working. I cannot even get the demo to work either (in any browsers).

I was using 1.7.2 up until a few minutes ago, when I upgraded. I swear I had it working  last night, yet this afternoon it wasn't working so thought it best to upgrade first, before posting here. However I have had no luck in getting it working.

Is anyone else experiencing the same problem? Anyone had the same problem in the past and managed to solve it somehow?

If it is working for other people then I will post my code here, but at the moment I don't feel the need to do so as it will just take up space.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Richard

Example removed - replaced with http://jsfiddle.net/Z6mJU/. It appears to be working here, so maybe I don't have jQuery set up correctly... I haven't fiddled with the masterpage much but apparently I have removed something vital, or so it seems. I will have another fiddle and see if I can solve it. Will post back here later with my progress.

Comment: An example could would be helpful for repro.

Comment: Added an example of the code I am using - I will see about creating a jsfiddle in a mo and post back here.

Comment: Ok added the jsfiddle. It appears to work there. Dunno what I have done since last night but something has gone horribly wrong. Strange that the demos are not working though - must just be a weird coincidence.

Comment: Looks like I may have solved it. The element on which I was trying to fade the colour was nested inside the element to which I added the class. So you have `div2` inside `div1`, and then something like `.div1 .div2 {background-color: #CCCCCC;}`. It was the outer div which I was adding the class to, but the inner div for which I wanted to change the colour. I need a class added to the outer div for other reasons so ended up adding a class to both, but only animating the class on the inner div. Hope this explains it well.

Comment: So it's necessary to add the class explicitly to the element being animated? No adding a class to an outer element to animate inner elements? That sucks...

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue with jQuery 1.5.1 and jQueryUI 1.8.12. I'd linked both libraries, but forgot to add in the bundled stylesheet. Adding  to my header fixed the problem.